# CBPeripheralManager connection callback

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to set up a bluetooth connection between two iOS devices. The idea is that one device offers a service and multiple devices connect to it:

Device A (service): User slides through a presentation

Device B (multiple clients): User watches the presentation, no interaction

In my understanding the one which offers the service should advertise it and respectively be the peripheral by creating a CBPeripheralManager and implement the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate -> Device A

On the other side, there are multiple central devices which scan for peripherals using the CBCentralManager and implementing the CBCentralManagerDelegate. After a connection is established they send read and write requests to the peripheral, using the CBPeripheral class and the CBPeripheralDelegate -> Device B

And now I get confused: From what I understood device A can not send information directly to device B and doesn't even recognize if a connection has been established or lost. But the clients (device B) can read and write data and get connect and disconnect notifications.

So my first idea was to swap the roles. Now the central device offers the service by scanning for devices which advertise that they want to use the service (?!?) and multiple peripherals can connect to one central device. Already sounds like it has to be wrong, right? And here comes the trouble: Now the periphals (users who watch the presentation) do not get notified anymore if a connection has been established or lost (aaahhhhh).

Now to the question: Is there a good way to make an iOS device a peripheral and recognize connects and disconnects (which should include disconnects by distance etc)?

ADDED: In WWDC 2012 Session 705 [(Link to presentation slides)](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_705__advanced_core_bluetooth.pdf) the methods central:didConnect and central:didDisconnect are mentioned. But even in the iOS 7 beta documentation of CBPeripheralManagerDelegate the methods are not mentioned. Maybe this is a dead end and Apple is laughing at me right now...

Thanks for any help!

Benjamin

Comment: Really wished I could find something to get notified of the connections. Any luck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make Device A (the presenter) the peripheral, advertising the service, and Device B (the viewers) the central, which subscribes to the peripheral's service.

You can use the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate to get notifications when a central has connected to your peripheral. Here's the documentation of the CBPeripheralManager delegate methods: [CBPeripheralManagerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate.html)

This is the method you need to implement to recognize when a central (Device B, a viewer) has connected to your peripheral (Device A, the presenter):

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
```

This is the method you need to recognize when a central (Device B, a viewer) has disconnected from your peripheral (Device A, the presenter):

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didUnsubscribeFromCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
```

When you need to notify the subscribed centrals (Device B, the viewers) that the slide has changed, use this method (newValue would be some kind of indicator of the updated position in the presentation, like slide number):

```
[self.peripheralManager updateValue:newValue forCharacteristic:yourCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
```

If you want to look through a simple demo of Bluetooth LE sharing with devices acting as both centrals and peripherals, you can check out this project: [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share/)

Hope that helps! Let me know if I can clarify something.

Laura

Comment: I tried peripheralManager:central:didSubscribeToCharacteristic: but it is never called. The signature says that it will be called on characteristic subscription, not on central connection. I am still looking for a way to get notified when a central connects.

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 10.3.3 on which I've written an app where I make the iPhone as a peripheral and connect to it using a BLE central device, there's no direct way for the iPhone to know when it is connected and when it is disconnected.

Notification subscription or Write command/request to a characteristic can be considered as a way of knowing that the central has connected, but detecting a disconnection is still tricky. I observed that even when BLE central disconnects, the 'didUnsubscribeFromCharacteristic' API does not get fired up until it actually does the unsubscription on its own.

What I've done is used a timer which restarts itself every time a 'write to characteristic' is received. When it times out, I declare that the connection is lost.

I don't understand why doesn't Apple provide APIs for such small, basic things and make our implementations (and our lives) so hard?!