# How do I get notified if a connection is established in bluetooth settings of iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a iPhone which is trying to connect to a peripheral through my app, the connection drops after a min for some reason(not the issue). My app does not try to auto reconnect to this peripheral, but in the iPhone settings I can see that the peripheral is still shown as connected.
I get the disconnect callback from the CoreBluetooth framework, but no following didConnect callback because the app is not trying to connect again.

Is there any way I can know in my app when the system auto connects to this peripheral?. Or any system notifications I can subscribe in order to know when the connection status changes?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574399/cbperipheralmanager-connection-callback

Comment: If the peripheral disconnects, it is your app's responsibility to issue a new `connect` call, if that is what you want

Comment: @Paulw11 consider this scenario. I am connected to a device through my app, if the device and phone are far from each other then they are disconnected, and when they come back in range they get connected again. How can my app be notified that the device is back in range and send a connect call? Searching for the device in background will use up lot of battery wouldn't it?

Comment: You don't have to; Simply issue a `connect` as soon as the peripheral disconnects and that connect will be pending.  Once the device comes back into range the connection will complete and your app will be notified.  If you haven't adopted Core Bluetooth background mode then the connection will only complete once your app is back in the foreground with the device in range.

Comment: so it is basically an auto reconnect?

Comment: yes, but your code needs to specifically request a connection before iOS will do it.

Comment: @Paulw11 so if my phone connects before my app then a `connect` request will not be received on the device? or it will just subscribe to the services and characteristics directly?

Comment: Core Bluetooth provides a layer of abstraction from the hardware.  Your app connects to a "virtual" peripheral that is provided by Core Bluetooth. Once the connection is in place you get a call to the `didConnect` delegate method as usual. What you do then is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth framework gives you a delegate method to know the status of the Bluetooth connectivity.

```
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

var bluetoothPeripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:0] 
    bluetoothPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    var statusMessage = ""

    switch peripheral.state {
    case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Turned On"

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOff:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Turned Off"

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.Resetting:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Resetting"

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.Unauthorized:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Not Authorized"

    case CBPeripheralManagerState.Unsupported:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Not Supported"

    default:
        statusMessage = "Bluetooth Status: Unknown"
    }
    print(statusMessage)
  }
}
```

This `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` method gives you the state of the bluetooth. Hope it helps.Get the status message and do according to your needs.

Comment: Will this be triggered if the OS connects to the device and not through my app?

Comment: only through the app